# How to throw form error separately in angular js material?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-material

I am using angularjs meterial and trying to throw errors separately. I have a simple form in which there is textarea and i am applying `maxlength` and `required` in it like this.

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="addEditPromocodeForm" ng-submit="addEdit.addPromoCodeInPopup(addEdit.bank);">

  <md-input-container>
                     <label>PromoText</label>
                     <textarea rows="3" id="promoText" name="promoText" ng-model="addEdit.promoText"  ng-maxlength="150" required></textarea>
                            required : {{addEditPromocodeForm.promoText.$error.required}} <br>
                            max length : {{addEditPromocodeForm.promoText.$error.maxlength}}<br>
                            error : {{addEditPromocodeForm.promoText.$error | json}}
                            <div ng-messages="addEditPromocodeForm.promoText.$error" >
                                <div class="error"  ng-message="required">PromoText is required</div>
                                <div class="error"  ng-message="maxlength">PromoText is too long</div>
                            </div>
                        </md-input-container>
        </form>
```

but unfortunately i see two errors every time. Although i see clearly in the `$error` array that when the specific error comes, the `$error` array contains only that specific error. like this

```
error : { "required": true }
```

and if `maxlength` error comes the `$error` array becomes like this

```
error : { "maxlength": true }
```

But still i get two errors why ???

Comment: you better use `md-maxlength` instead of  `ng-maxlength` and then add `ng-message="md-maxlength"` in the message area.

Comment: used it sir but still not working like expected :( :( :(